# Using QuickContactBadge in a listview

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a listview that gets contact information with a QuickContactBadge, but nothing appears where the QuickContactBadge is suppose to be. How do I do this?

Adapter creation:

```
String[] fields = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.Data.PHOTO_ID,
            ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.Data.PHOTO_ID
    };
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.contract_list_entry, cursor,
            fields, new int[] {R.id.contactEntryPicture, R.id.contactEntryName, R.id.contactEntryAmount});
```

Listview item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <QuickContactBadge android:id="@+id/contactEntryPicture" android:layout_height="54dp" android:layout_width="54dp"></QuickContactBadge>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView android:id="@+id/contactEntryName" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="TextView" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="TextView" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/contactEntryAmount"></TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your fields array you have PHOTO_ID twice. Did you mean to do that?

Comment: Yes, its for debugging purposes to see if anything is actually there. I have the PHOTO_ID being displayed as text also. I haven't implemented Amount yet.